# Mapbox GL JS Change the color from the default marker

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I’m starting to loose my mind.

According to [Mapbox API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) I should be able to change the default marker color but I didn't find any exemple in the documentation that doesn't use custom markers and the most likely syntax doesn't work.

I am using `mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.2`

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({ "color": "#b40219" })
                .setLngLat([0, 0])
                .addTo(map);
```

With this code, the map is shown without the marker and if I remove the color option the marker does display correctly but with the wrong color.

Any suggestion to where I messed up ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for custom colors when using the default Marker SVG element is available since `v0.45.0`, you are using `v0.44.2`.

Release notes:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases

Comment: The syntax is correct `const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({ "color": "#b40219" })`

Answer (score 8):

Screw jQuery

```
setMarkerColor(marker, color) {
      let markerElement = marker.getElement();
      markerElement
        .querySelectorAll('svg g[fill="' + marker._color + '"]')[0]
        .setAttribute("fill", color);
      marker._color = color;
    },
```

Comment: This code changes color of the marker's shade if previous color is `#000000`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pILu.png

Answer (score 4):

And if you need to change the color of the default marker on the fly you may use this kind of function (used jQuery to get element's children):

```
function setMarkerColor(marker, color) {
    var $elem = jQuery(marker.getElement());
    $elem.find('svg g[fill="' + marker._color + '"]').attr('fill', color);
    marker._color = color;
}
```

Comment: I've just copied and pasted it and works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

when setting up the marker, put the color in the brackets:

`new mapboxgl.Marker({ "color": "#b40219" }) //this changes color to a dark red// .setLngLat([-74.5, 40]) .addTo(map);`

Answer (score 0):

```
marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        color: $parameters.UpdatedMarkerColor,
        draggable: false
    });
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.